# Publish Failed on WebSphere Application Server v8.0

Tags: java, websphere-8, ibm-rad

Im using RAD v8 and I've installed WAS v8.0 I can start the server and while its running I try to publish the ear file it gives me the following error:

The publish encountered some problems and the application may not have been installed or it may have been successfully installed but was unable to start.
ADMA0176E: Application installation of excsEAR failed with PrivilegedActionException.  Ear file path is \SALSMOSXF03\Redir\GRQBB0\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\excsEAR.

Help!

Comment: Is that a maven project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out!! Silly me...  I was using my workplace network drive as my workspace I thought it was a local folder!! Once I created a new workspace on C: drive everything works fine.. WOOOHOOOO

Comment: This is really not a solution, you are just recreating the workspace where you have access. This error sometimes occurs even when the workspace is on C drive.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to solve it delete your {{application}}.ear from below locations

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/{{profilename}}/config/temp/download/cells/applications

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/{{profilename}}/config/temp/download/cells/cus

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/{{profilename}}/config/temp/download/cells/blas

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/{{profilename}}/config/cells/{{Nodename}}/applications

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/{{profilename}}/config/cells/{{Nodename}}/blas

/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/{{profilename}}/config/cells/{{Nodename}}/cus